# out put value is null when calling to mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I try to call a mysql stored procedure within a stored procedure. But when calling to the procedure inside the procedure value  output is null. Inside the procedure declaration I have declared a out variable to get the value from when calling to the SP. as example 
but when calling to the procedure externally it will getting  a value.

```
CALL  Test1('cccro1', @CbslDetail_)
```

When calling to the Test2 I'm unable to get the value @CbslDetail_

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE Call Test2 ``(
FROMDATE DATE,
TODATE   DATE,
OUT CbslDetail_   VARCHAR(2000)
)

CALL Test1('cccro1', @CbslDetail_)

select @CbslDetail_
```

Comment: Your sample sp name is different than what you have shared and share more info about the other sp as well. What result you are expecting as OUT?

Comment: that's a mistake I have updated it

Comment: what param parsed?

Comment: `CALL Test1('cccro1', @CbslDetail_)`  **cccro1** is the value which is parsing. **@CbslDetail_** it the variable which is output from the procedure. I want to get that value.

Comment: have you tried set the value to the OUT var like `SET CbslDetail_=@CbslDetail_`

Comment: If you need how `OUT` works look this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: I checking on it. Thank you